# How to create n-gram in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, n-gram, trigram

I want search functionality in my application.

I used trigram for achieving it and it is working fine.

**Problem is:**

trigram is creating sequence of 3 character group of word.
I want more than 3 character in single object.
For Example:

```
select show_trgm('abcpqrs');
```

This will return: `{"  a"," ab","abc","bcp","cpq","pqr","qrs","rs "}`

I want `{"  a"," ab","abc","bcp","cpq","pqr","qrs","rs ","abcd","bcpq","cpqr"...}`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could create a user-defined function to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myngram(mystr TEXT, n INT) RETURNS TEXT[]
AS $$
DECLARE
str VARCHAR;
arr TEXT[];
BEGIN

  str := lpad(mystr, n - 1 + char_length(mystr), ' ');
  str := rpad(str, n - 1 + char_length(str), ' ');

  arr := array[]::TEXT[];
  FOR i IN 1 .. char_length(str) - n + 1 LOOP
    arr := arr || substring(str from i for n);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN arr;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Results from my testing.

```
testdb=# SELECT myngram('abcpqrs', 4);
                             myngram                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 {"   a","  ab"," abc",abcp,bcpq,cpqr,pqrs,"qrs ","rs  ","s   "}
(1 row)

testdb=# SELECT myngram('abcpqrs', 5);
                                       myngram                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"    a","   ab","  abc"," abcp",abcpq,bcpqr,cpqrs,"pqrs ","qrs  ","rs   ","s    "}
(1 row)
```

Comment: This works fine... but it could be improved by using `LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT`: IMMUTABLE because it will return the same result for the same arguments - then can be better planned by PostgreSQL and STRICT because it will fail on null input - with STRICT it will return NULL