# How to implement efficient search-as-you-type in postgres using edge n-grams

Tags: postgresql, performance, elasticsearch, n-gram

I want to implement search-as-you-type functionality into my postgres database. I believe this requires n-grams, to be able to match an incomplete word to a longer string.

I have looked at the [edge n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) from elasticsearch. This tokenizes phrases into n-grams. For example:

```
'2 Quick Foxes.' => [ Qu, Qui, Quic, Quick, Fo, Fox, Foxe, Foxes ]
```

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581669/how-to-create-n-gram-in-postgresql) to get equivalent functionality in postgres.

I am now wondering how I can efficiently query over a database containing rows of these edge n-grams, with a query such as "Quick Fo".